# PyTorch DatasetLoader tensor should be a torch tensor. Got <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch, python-imaging-library

```
data_dir="D:\ML-ComputerVision\Datasets"
train_transforms=transforms.Compose([transforms.RandomRotation(30),
                                     transforms.RandomResizedCrop(100),
                                     transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                    transforms.Normalize([0.5,],[0.5,]),
                                    transforms.ToTensor()])

test_transforms=transforms.Compose([transforms.Normalize([0.5,],[0.5,]),
                                    transforms.ToTensor()])

train_data=datasets.ImageFolder(data_dir + "/Train",transform=train_transforms)

test_data=datasets.ImageFolder(data_dir + "/Test",transform=test_transforms)

trainloader=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data,batch_size=32,shuffle=True)

testloader=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data,batch_size=32,shuffle=False)

images, labels = next(iter(trainloader)) # <-- Error line
```

I am getting  tensor should be a torch tensor. Got <class 'PIL.Image.Image'> error even though I have implemented transforms.ToTensor(). Any ideas how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you chained your transforms, `transforms.Normalize`is applied before `transforms.ToTensor`. But even though `RandomRotation`, `RandomResizedCrop` and `RandomHorizontalFlip` are image transforms that work on PIL images, `transforms.Normalize` only works on tensors (documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Normalize)).

Simply putting `ToTensor` before `Normalize` should work.

Answer (score 2):

`transforms.Normalize([0.5,],[0.5,])` is applied on Tensor, so `transforms.ToTensor()` has to be before normalization.